# Java regex to split along words, punctuation, and whitespace, and keep all in an array

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a sentence into  a group of strings. I want to keep all words, punctuation and whitespace in an array.

For example:

"Hello! My name is John Doe."

Would be split into:

```
["Hello", "!", " ", "My", " ", "name", " ", "is", " ", "John", " ", "Doe"]
```

I currently have the following line of code breaking my sentence:

```
String[] fragments = sentence.split("(?<!^)\\b");
```

However, this is running into an error where it counts a punctuation mark followed by a whitespace as a single string. How do I modify my regex to account for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary to scream *Need help!* in your title or your post. It's obvious you need help, or you wouldn't be posting here in the first place. Everyone who posts a question here needs help. Please spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] pages, particularly [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Will your text ever contain text like `"What!?"` How should `!?` be treated?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following regular expression:

```
(?<=\b|[^\p{L}])
```

```
"Hello! My name is John Doe.".split("(?<=\\b|[^\\p{L}])", 0) 
// ⇒ ["Hello", "!", " ", "My", " ", "name", " ", "is", " ", "John", " ", "Doe", "."]
```

Comment: Nice. BTW negation of `\p{...}` is `\P{...}` so you can use `\\P{L}` instead of `[^\\p{L}]`.

Comment: @Pshemo Awesome! Thank you!